# Neo4j Query - Relations that one property is NOT EQUAL to a value in none of relations grouped by another property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Sorry for the title. I couldn't find a better one. My question is hard for me to explain in words so I'll try to give an example.

Say I have a relation named "FOO" and "FOO" has two property named "id" and "bar".

And there is a graph like this:

```
(n1)-[:FOO {id: "1", bar:"8"}]->(n2)-[:FOO {id: "1", bar:"27"}]->(n3)-[:FOO {id: "1", bar:"50"}]->(n4)

(m1)-[:FOO {id: "4", bar:"2"}]->(m2)-[:FOO {id: "4", bar:"12"}]->(n2)-[:FOO {id: "4", bar:"25"}]->(m3)

(n1)-[:FOO {id: "7", bar:"11"}]->(m2)-[:FOO {id: "7", bar:"50"}]->(o3)-[:FOO {id: "7", bar:"14"}]->(o5)
```

And so on...

What I want to do is getting all ids (or nodes and relations related to those ids) for the relation series doesn't have any "bar" property equal to 50.

In above graph, the result I want is second one, **id: "4"**:

```
(m1)-[:FOO {id: "4", bar:"2"}]->(m2)-[:FOO {id: "4", bar:"12"}]->(m3)-[:FOO {id: "4", bar:"25"}]->(m3)
```

Plus to this query how can I get the all ids (or nodes and relations related to those ids) for the relation series whose last relations bar property is not equal to 50. In this one, what I would like to get is first and third one, **id: "4"** and **id: "7"** :

```
(m1)-[:FOO {id: "4", bar:"2"}]->(m2)-[:FOO {id: "4", bar:"12"}]->(n2)-[:FOO {id: "4", bar:"25"}]->(m3)

(n1)-[:FOO {id: "7", bar:"11"}]->(m2)-[:FOO {id: "7", bar:"50"}]->(o3)-[:FOO {id: "7", bar:"14"}]->(o5)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UNWIND [1, 4, 7] AS rel_id
MATCH path = () - [:FOO*3 {id:rel_id}] -> ()
WHERE NOT ANY(x IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) WHERE x.bar = '50')
RETURN path
```

And for number 2:

```
UNWIND [1, 4, 7] AS rel_id
MATCH path = () - [:FOO*3 {id: rel_id}] -> ()
WHERE NOT LAST(RELATIONSHIPS(path))['bar'] = '50'
RETURN RELATIONSHIPS(path)[0]['id']
```

This is basically the minimal framework to answer your problem. If you need to narrow down the possible paths, you can prefix the queries with something else to alias the nodes or relationships that you want to build the paths on.

EDIT: To get all possible ID's instead of passing the list in manually, replace the first line with:

```
MATCH () - [r:FOO] - ()
WITH r.id AS r_id
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT r_id) AS rel_ids
UNWIND rel_ids AS rel_id
```

Comment: Thanks. 

There are many id's in the graph. There is no way I could give them manually like you wrote. Is there another way for it ?

Also there could be more relation than 3. Is there a way to get the path no matter how many relation does it contains ?

Comment: See the edit above to pass in different ID's. As for the `*` notation, check out [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#_variable_length).

Comment: `MATCH () - [r:FOO] - ()
WITH r.id AS r_id
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT r_id) AS rel_ids
UNWIND rel_ids AS rel_id
MATCH path = () - [:FOO {id:rel_id}] -> ()
WHERE NOT ANY(x IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) WHERE x.bar = 50)
RETURN RELATIONSHIPS(path)[0]['id']`

I tried this query, but "WHERE NOT ANY" part doesn't do anything. The result is the same with or without it.

Comment: When you use a relationship property like this (`foo.bar`) instead of different relationship types, the DB has to make all possible traversals and then filter them by property; those properties aren't part of the traversal info stored on the nodes/relationships. If you leave the length unbounded too, it's going to keep building _every_ possible path of `FOO`, and _only then_ try to filter them out based on the id/bar condition (very wasteful). Replace `FOO` with a distinct type for each `id` property value and your query might be graphable.

Comment: As for the issue with the query, you've formatted your numeric properties as strings, so there's a mismatch. If you really mean them to be numeric properties, remove the quotes, Cypher can handle number types. Numbers are faster to process for equality than strings, and less deceptive to people reading your query. See edits.

Comment: I couldn't make this type of query work. I managed to get results in a different way. Thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this is the correct way to do it but I managed to get **first** results I wanted like this:

```
MATCH () - [r:FOO] - ()
WHERE r.bar = "50" 
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT r.id) as bar50_ids
MATCH () - [r:FOO] - ()
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT r.id) as all_ids, bar50_ids
RETURN [x IN all_ids WHERE NOT(x IN bar50_ids)] AS barnot50_ids
```

(Getting the DISTINCT id's whose in all its relation at least one .bar = "50", and getting their difference from all DISTINC id's will give the all id's that has not any relation contains bar = "50")

I don't know how to get the **second** one I wanted.